# parametric func() selection in <body onload="func()" > tag depending on argument parameter in html

Tags: javascript, html, header

I have an index.html running a menu

```
<a href='./satellites.html'> 
<a href='./simulation.html'>
```

The server responds by sending one of the two files requested and a header.
The two files (satellites.html and simulation.html) are almost the same with the only difference in the function that is called when loaded

```
<!-- in the satellites.html-->
<body onload='init()'>            
...

and 
<!-- in the simulation.html-->
<body onload='initSimulation()'>  
...
```

Otherwise, the two HTML programs are identical.

Everything works fine but I want to avoid repeating the same code. How can the server control which function the client will call (using URL parameters probably)? I searched but it seems that the header is not available neither in HTML or in javascript.

Comment: I could have the server edit the file before sending it, but the added overhead is not a viable solution.

Comment: ***...the header is not available neither in HTML or in javascript*** which header?

Comment: The header the server is including in its responce to the request

Comment: @kiner_shah You are right, my question left some points missing, so I edited it.

Comment: So basically you want only one file and based on some flag, the respective onload function should be called? BTW is this server code owned by you?

Comment: @kiner_shah, Yes! exactly. Yes I write both the server and the client code

Comment: Initially separate requests are made by client for each file so it's easy to distinguish. So now do you expect the client to give some query parameter example, `your-url.domain?isSimulation=true`? If yes and if you own the server code, you need to get this parameter value from the URL, construct the HTML page accordingly and then send the response.

Comment: No, that would not avoid having two separate HTML functions in the server. What I'm looking for is the server to have only one file in its (limited) memory and send it to the client including a parameter in the header. Then the client to process the header and decide which function to call. 
Another idea is for the client to remember which file it requested and set a cookie. Then depending on the set cookie to select the appropriate function. 
The server is a small ESP32 device with limited resources (an IOT application)

Answer (score 0):

Using cookies offers a solution, which I do not like because some users do not allow cookies. But nevertheless, I include it here for reference:
In the index.html (the clientside menu):

```
<!-- in index.html-->
<body>
   ...
   <a href='./satellites.html' class='button'>
   <a onclick="return false" ondblclick="startSimulation()" class='button'>
   ...
   <script>
       function startSimulation(){
          document.cookie = "simulation=true";
          window.location.replace("./AISsatellites.html");
       }
    </script>
</body>
```

Now the server stores and sends always the same file.
The client via the cookie decides which function to call as follows:

```
<!-- in satellites.html-->   
<body onload='select_Simulation_or_Online()'>
...
   <script>
      function select_Simulation_or_Online(){
         if(document.cookie.indexOf('simulation=')==0) {
            simulation = true;
            document.cookie = 'simulation=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
            initSimulation();
         }
        else {
            simulation = false;
            init();
        }
   ...
   </script>
</body>
```

Still looking for a solution without the use of cookies - possibly using a parameter that the server places in the header, to be read by the client.